Nuxt assets/public SVG files don't reflect changes
When storing svg files for icons in either my assets OR public folder, If I make any changes to the svg, I need to rename the file and restart my dev server for the changes to be reflected. All past iterations of the svg are also still loadable in components even though the filename has changed.
How can I set up my build so as to not have to rename the file every time I update it?
In my nuxt.config.ts I have the following for a custom set of icons that I am using via the Nuxt UI UIcon component.
icon: {
    customCollections: [
      {
        prefix: 'my-icons',
        dir: '~assets/my-icons' //'./public/my-icons'
      }
    ]
  }

I have searched for similar issues and scoured the documentation, but have not found anything regarding this issue. Maybe I am fundamentally misunderstanding the build structure.
